# Responsive inline background images using jQuery data attributes

Tags: jquery, wordpress, image, background-image, responsive

I've written the following to potentially find an usable solution for responsive, inline background images with Wordpress:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  // BREAKPOINTS

  var lg = 1280,
      md = 1024,
      sm = 768,
      xs = 680,
      xxs = 400;

  var switch_background = function(){
    var breakpoints = {lg:1280,md:1024,sm:768,xs:680,xxs:400}; 

    var size = 'fullsize';
    var width = $(window).width();

    if(width <= breakpoints.xxs) {
      size = 'medium';
    } else if (width <= breakpoints.sm) {
      size = 'mediumlarge'; 
    }

    $(".bg-switch").css('background-image', function () {
      var bg = ('url(' + $(this).data(size) + ')');
      return bg;
    });
  }

  $(window).resize(function(){
    switch_background();
  });

  if ($(window).width() <= xxs){  
    switch_background()
  }

  if ($(window).width() > xxs && $(window).width() <= sm){  
    switch_background()
  }

});
```

The reason being that the background images can then be edited and changed using Wordpress.

This works in development, it replaces the images as expected at certain breakpoints when I resize the browser window.

However, will this actually give me the benefit of download, then showing the smaller image on a smaller device in practice?

Here's a flat HTML example on Codepen: http://codepen.io/abbasarezoo/pen/XpOqqY

Comment: Why would you do this when CSS Media Queries are specifically intended for this purpose and also faster due to being hardware accelerated?

Comment: Even then, media queries would be by far the better solution

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Not in this context. I want the ability to change/edit images in WP admin. You can't do that with a stylesheet, so inline is the way to go. It would be great if you could though.

Comment: You can read the data attribute using CSS's `content` rule: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content